# Show that if natural $m$ is even, then $2^{m} -1$ is not prime.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Show that if natural $m$ is even, then
$2^{m} -1$ is not prime.

As $m$ is even, so $m= 2n, n \in \mathbb{N}$. Hence,
$2^{2n} -1 \implies  (2^n)^2 -1^2 \implies  (2^n -1)(2^n+1)$.

So, need show either
$(2^{n} -1)$ or  $(2^n+1)$ is not prime.

Suppose if one of them is prime, then other is differing by $2$ only.

So, the problem reduces to showing that for any given prime $p\notin \{3,5,7\}$, $p\pm 2$ is not prime.

Request help.

Comment: If $A=(2^n -1)(2^n+1)$, then $A$ cannot be prime since it has two factors. ($n\in\mathbb{N}$) Holds for every $n$ except $n=1$.

Comment: To finish the proof, you need to show that atleast one of those factors is not 1 or the number itself.

Comment: $3$ always divides $2^{2n}-1$, because $2^2=4\equiv1$ mod $3$. So unless $2^{2n}-1=$ equals $3$, it's not prime. Actually for $n=1$ ($m=2$) it does equal $3$. So the claim is true for even $m$ greater than $2$.

Comment: @alex.jordan please make an answer, more so because modular arithmetic is used. Might be there is a generalization beneath this question.

Comment: You can actually use the recurrence  $2^{m+1}-1=2(2^m-1)+1$ and prove the $m$ have to be prime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the claim is false; if $ m $ is $ 2 $, then $ 2 ^ m - 1 $ *is* prime.  However, for all even $ m > 2 $, the claim is correct; in fact, in that case, $ 2 ^ m - 1 $ is composite.

In your question, you write that you need to show that either $ 2 ^ n - 1 $ or $ 2 ^ n + 1 $ is not prime.  But this is incorrect; to show that their product is composite, you need to show that either $ 2 ^ n - 1 $ or $ 2 ^ n + 1 $ is not *equal to $ 1 $*.  To show this, just set up the equations $ 2 ^ n - 1 = 1 $ and $ 2 ^ n + 1 = 1 $ and solve them; see what $ n $ would have to be (if there are even any solutions at all) and check that this is ruled out by the assumption that $ m > 2 $.  (Actually, because the subtraction could take you out of the system of positive integers, you should also check for solutions to $ 2 ^ n - 1 = 0 $ and $ 2 ^ n - 1 = - 1 $.  Still, you will find no solutions for $ n $ that are consistent with the assumption that $ 2 n $ is an even integer greater than $ 2 $.)

Answer (score 1):

If you take $2^{2n}-1$ mod $3$:
$$\begin{align}
2^{2n}-1&=4^{n}-1\\
&\equiv1^{n}-1\\
&\equiv0
\end{align}$$

So $3$ divides $2^{2n}-1$. Either the number is not prime, or it equals $3$. It equals $3$ exactly when $n=1$.

So for $n\geq2$, $2^{2n}-1$ is not prime. (And it's prime, equal to $3$, when $n=1$.)